# Java: Find similar strings

Tags: java, performance, similarity, levenshtein-distance

I have a java list (it could be a map if it is necessary) with a lot of strings.

- List(hello,hell,car,cartoon,...)

I want to find the most similar strings for another given string in an efficient way.

I think I should use the Levenshtein distance, but I don't want to iterate through all the list.

Do you think that it is a good idea to divide the main list in some pieces with a common prefix?

Then I would have a map with prefixes as the key and with a list as the value:

- hel -> List(hello,hell,...)
- car -> List(car,cartoon,...)

In this way I could search quickly the strings with the same prefix that the searched one. Then I could apply the Levenshtein distance only for some strings and not for all the main-list.

Is it a good idea? Thanks

Comment: try Trie data structure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: Would Streams be good enough?  You could use Streams.filter?

Comment: mapping by prefix will not work: what happens if the only difference in the two words is in the first or second  letter?

Comment: You're right FredK, I'm assuming that the first three letters given by the user are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could once calculate the [**soundex**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) code of every entry, and map soundex to list of original word. Soundex is a reducing code to get one single key for similar sounding words.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> soundexToWords = ...
for (String word : words) {
    String sdex = soundex(word);
    Set<String> similarWords = soundexToWords.get(sdex));
    if (similarWords == null) {
        similarWords = new HashSet<>();
        soundexToWords.put(sdex, similarWords);
    }
    similarWords.add(word);
}

Set<String> similarWords(String word) {
    return soundexToWords.get(soundex(word));
}
```

Soundex is typically for one language, say English, and especially for English is quite reducive.

Comment: It is a very good idea. The map indexing would be O(n) and the search will be O(1). Thanks a lot, i think it probably is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple Solution

The simplest solution is to first call `Collections.sort()` on your `List`. Now your list is sorted in [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). Next, perform a binary search on the list to find where your prefix belongs. The index that's returned basically gives you the position of the most similar word.

You can then construct your map by either mapping the prefix to the index, so you can retrieve the subset of the overall `List` upon demand, or you can cache the subset itself in the map. This subset is a list, starting at that index in the overall `List`, whose elements are of descending similarity. You can fine-tune the stop index to be once the first letter increments or something similar.

#### Best Solution

The best solution is to take a look at the [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure. A trie supports `O(m)` queries, where `m` is the length of the prefix you're searching for. This takes up **far less space** and avoids hash collisions. While your map theoretically supports `O(1)` queries, the build time is `O(n^2)` if you store each list explicitly. If you store indices, the build time is linear, but then each request is `O(n)`.

Comment: Your solution will depend on how you define what you mean by "most similar". For example, which of these is most similar to the word "flammable":
 inflammable or flappable

Comment: Thanks for tell me about the tries. It looks really great. I will consider it

Comment: Right, but the OP only provided examples of prefixes, which lends itself easily to the trie data structure. Otherwise, I agree that it's not so clear-cut.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<String> similarWords(String word, List<String> allWords){
    List<String> similarWordList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String currentWord : allWords){
        if(currentWord.contains(word)){
            similarWordList.add(currentWord);
        }
    }
    return similarWordList;
}
```

Comment: OP clearly states, that they do not want to iterate through the entire list.